# Time complexity of StringBuilder length() method

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

What is the time complexity of length() method from StringBuilder class?

```
String str = "hello";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

System.out.println(sb.length()); // should print 5
```

My assumption is O(n) where n is number of characters in the string, similar to length() from String class.

Comment: It's O(1).  The length is stored in an instance field and simply returned in one simple operation.

Comment: Importantly, it's O(1) for `String`, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a member variable in `StringBuilder` class:

```
/**
 * The count is the number of characters used.
 */
int count;
```

And this is the code of `length()`:

```
/**
 * Returns the length (character count).
 *
 * @return  the length of the sequence of characters currently
 *          represented by this object
 */
@Override
public int length() {
    return count;
}
```

What do you think?